# Where can I ask a shopping question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

If I'm looking for a tool or set of tools (software, mostly) to do something that I'm clearly not knowledgeable enough to create on my own, how can I get that without asking an off-topic shopping question on SE?

In other words, if I were to create my own tools, I could ask about all the details in multiple questions, and all of them would be perfectly legitimate.  But what if I want to just use a tool that someone else probably made already?  How do I find that?

I'm sure there are lots of people on the SE network that would know.  The only problem is that it's not allowed to ask here as far as I can tell.

Comment: @PolyGeo At first, I thought, "Mmm, not really," because I think mine is more general, but as I think about it more, you're probably right. (If we could only encode direct concepts and not just words, sounds, and pictures, maybe searches would work better.) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a software to accomplish some specific task, you can ask your question on [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). However, you should read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) first to make sure your question is not off-topic.